# Include Parameter in SELECT as Column

Tags: sql, parameters, devexpress, report-designer

In a parameterized query, I want to include the parameter as an additional column in the result. How do I do this?

I tried something like

```
SELECT tbl.colA, tbl.colB, :START_DATE AS START_DATE, :END_DATE AS END_DATE
FROM table_name tbl
WHERE tbl.start_date >= :START_DATE
AND tbl.end_date <= :END_DATE
```

Doing the above, I get this error:

`Type of the parameter 'START_DATE' is ambiguous.`

Comment: Tag dbms product used. (Seems to be a product specific behavior.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using the Report Designer tool from DevExpress.